# converting the tag names in JSON to follow CamelCase notation

Tags: xml, json, perl

I am having a JSON like following :

```
{
    "Person": {
       "IDCountry": "0", 
       "Home": {
          "ID": "ABC-XYZ", 
           "Laptop": {
             "FileName": "/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz",
             "Key": "123456789"
           }, 

          "Location": {
              "Number": "62", 
              "MaxSize": "0"
           }, 
        }
    }
 }
```

This JSON is getting generated from some separate method from an XML file in perl using following code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use JSON;
    use XML::Simple;
    use XML::LibXML;
    # Create the object of XML Simple
    my $xmlSimple = new XML::Simple(KeepRoot   => 1);

    # Load the xml file in object
    my $dataXML = eval { $xmlSimple->XMLin($xmlFileName)};

    # use encode json function to convert xml object in json.
    my $jsonString = eval { encode_json($dataXML) };

    print $jsonString;
```

Everything is working fine here. But i want to get the output JSON tag names as all lower case. That is i want my output like this.

```
 {
    "person": {
       "idCountry": "0", 
       "home": {
          "id": "ABC-XYZ", 
           "laptop": {
             "fileName": "/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz",
             "key": "123456789"
           }, 

          "location": {
              "number": "62", 
              "maxSize": "0"
           }, 
        }
    }
 }
```

My current output JSON tags has same name as the name of elements in the xml file from which it is being generated.

How can i make change in my current perl script to have the tags in json all following  camel case notations.

Thanks.

JSON for case when we want to handle condition that specific element gets lower case and specific element gets camel case.

```
 {
    "person": {
       "idcountry": "0", 
       "home": {
          "id": "ABC-XYZ", 
           "laptop": {
             "fileName": "/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz",
             "key": "123456789"
           }, 

          "location": {
              "number": "62", 
              "maxSize": "0"
           }, 
        }
    }
 }
```

If you will see maxSize and fileName are following camelCase convention but all other tags got lower case.

That is we have two list :

{ FileName, MaxSize } these gets converted following came case whereas 
{ Person, IDCountry, Home, ID, Laptop, Key, Location, Number } all gets converted into lower case.

Answer (score 1):

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairmap );

my %override = map { fc($_) => $_ } qw( maxSize fileName );

sub fix {
   my ($arg) = @_;

   defined($arg)
      or return;

   my $reftype = ref($arg)
      or return;

   if ($reftype eq 'ARRAY') {
      fix($_) for @$arg;
   }
   elsif ($reftype eq 'HASH') {
      %$arg = pairmap { $override{fc($a)} // lc($a), $b } %$arg;

      fix($_) for values(%$arg);
   }
}

my $data = { Person => { ... } };
fix($data);
```

---

For backwards compatibility, you can replace

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairmap );

my %override = map { fc($_) => $_ } qw( maxSize fileName );

%$arg = pairmap { $override{fc($a)} // lc($a), $b } %$arg;
```

with

```
my %override = map { lc($_) => $_ } qw( maxSize fileName );

my @old_keys = keys(%$arg);
my @new_keys = map { $override{lc($_)} || lc($_) } @old_keys;
@$arg{@new_keys} = delete( @$arg{@old_keys} );
```

Comment: can you please explain what this code is doing, few comments in code should be helpful.

Comment: @user1188611 read it out loud. This code does not need any comments.

Comment: yes sorry it was obvious code, by comment i meant to say how i can integrate it in  my use case. I am a sophomore in coding ( not much coding background ) so asked this, let me try to integrate it. Thanks

Comment: Change `lc` to `lcfirst`.

Comment: Fixed a bug in my answer.

Comment: @ikegami: one quick question how will you handle the condition when i want few specific element to be lower case and few to be camel case... i tried creating two hash one for list of lower case tags and for list of camel case tags and based on match do corresponding operation... That seemed to be not working, any pointers... Updated the question to have an example

Comment: Re "i am not asking to give me solution directed integrated", I already did anyway. Just add `fix($data);` before `encode_json($data)`.

Comment: `@$` makes no sense. `@$arg{@new_keys}` is a hash slice. It's the slice (values) of the hash referenced by `$arg` with the keys `@new_keys`. It's the same as `($arg->{$new_keys[0]}, $arg->{$new_keys[1]}, ...)`. As you noticed that part of the code never changed in any of your tweaks. The mapping of old keys to new keys is performed by `pairmap`/`map`'s `BLOCK`.